# change the values of dynamic form control angular

Tags: angular

I have this dynamic form control

```
<form [formGroup]="dynamicFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >

 <div class="row" formArrayName="address" *ngFor="let fields of AddressInfo.controls; let i = index">
            <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
 <input type="number" class="form-control height-reset" placeholder="Enter Mobile" name="mobile" formControlName="mobile" />
..
</form>
```

when i try to change the value of fields

```
this.dynamicFormGroup.controls['mobile'].setValue('');
```

or

```
this.dynamicFormGroup.patchValue({ mobile: '444' });
```

the value is not updating

Any solution Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to update on button click or on page load ?

Comment: @JavascriptHuppTechnologies Update on button click, its dynamic form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, it is not clear what `AddressInfo` is. Instead, change your code to this:

```html
<div class="row" formArrayName="address" *ngFor="let fields of addressFormArray.controls; let i = index">
  <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
    <input type="number" class="form-control height-reset" placeholder="Enter Mobile" name="mobile" formControlName="mobile">
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

```js
get addressFormArray() {
  return this.formMain.get('address') as FormArray;
}
```

User may now add a value.

If your plan is to edit that value programmatically,  `this.dynamicFormGroup.controls['mobile'].setValue('');` will not work, since `mobile` is a FormControl within a FormArray. Then, either you have you to loop through that array to change all values or you have to clarify which value should be changed.

**Update**

Based on your comment, I assume that your goal is to change the value of mobile, if it starts with 0 (if not, please update your question).

```html
<div class="row" formArrayName="address" *ngFor="let fields of addressFormArray.controls; let i = index">
  <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
    <input (input)="updateMobile(i)" class="form-control height-reset" placeholder="Enter Mobile" name="mobile" formControlName="mobile">
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

```js
updateMobile(index: number) {
  const formArray = this.formMain.get('address') as FormArray;
  const mobileControl = formArray.at(index).get('mobile') as FormControl;
  const value = mobileControl.value;
  if (value.startsWith('0')) {
    const modifiedValue = '+1' + value.substring(1);
    mobileControl.setValue(modifiedValue);
  }
}
```

So if the value is 0123456789, it will be replaced with +1123456789 (you can replace `+1` to whatever you want). If you want to keep `+`, please ensure you have removed `type="number"` or replaced it with `type="tel"`.

If your goal is to change the value of first mobile field only, you can use

```js
this.addressFormArray.at(0).get('mobile')?.patchValue("My Value");
```

Comment: I want to change zero index value of mobile

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using a FormControl inside a FormArray inside a formGroup. ( just form lookin at the short code snippet)

So your code should looke something like;

```js
this.dynamicFormGroup.controls[index].controls['mobile'].setValue('');
```

The `<ng-container [formGroupName]="i">` might break it as well.

I would recommend to revise the structur of the forms and then find the correct "path" to each.

Comment: Thanks getting this error `Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl`